# How to create a 100% fixed footer with a fixed width center transparent gap?

Tags: html, css, sticky-footer

How to create a 100% fixed footer with a fixed width center transparent gap?
No scripts!

EXPAND THIS WAY <<< ***_*__*_*__** FIXED WIDTH GAP **__*_*__*_*** >>> EXPAND THIS WAY

**MY OWN SOLUTION**

**HTML**

```
<div id="Ftr">
  <div id="FtrL"></div>
  <div id="FtrM"></div>
  <div id="FtrR"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#Ftr {
    position: fixed;
    height: 115px;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 21;
}
#FtrL,
#FtrR {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: calc(50% - 360px);
    width: -webkit-calc(50% - 360px);
}
#FtrL {
    background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_left.png') repeat-x;
    left: 0;
}
#FtrR {
    background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_left.png') repeat-x;
    right: 0;
}
#FtrM {
    background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_middle.png') no-repeat;
    height: 115px;
    width: 720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

See the live data here: 
http://www.dreamtek.info

Comment: show us the HTML part and try to make a demo at jsfiddle.net

Comment: are you forbidden to use javascript or a small piece of it will work for you?

Comment: since you have the same background image on the left and right part: wouldn't setting that on the whole footer do the trick?

Comment: No because the center div has transparency and the footer would be visible behind the center image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using only **CSS** with CSS3 **calc function** help:

You can define side DIV elements width using the following CSS property:

```
width: calc((100% - 200px) / 2); /* browsers with native support */
width: -webkit-calc((100% - 200px) / 2); /* webkit browsers support, Chrome, Safari... */
width: -moz-calc((100% - 200px) / 2); /* Firefox support */
```

where **200px** is the center DIV fixed width. This way the remaining horizontal space will be filled equally by both side DIV elements. Be aware that this is not a cross browser compatible solution. You might need to use javascript if you want one **(if so see my other answer)**

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JmSyw/)

+1 for the author of the question for reminding me of **webkit-calc**

Comment: ok reps to you and many thanks for your help.
note: you need to add 
width: calc((100% - 200px) / 2);
For firefox

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>


#footer {
  position: fixed; left: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden; width: 100%;
}

#footer .left {
  float: left: width: 200px; height: 115px;
  background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_left.png') repeat-x;
}

#footer .right {
  float: right: width: 200px; height: 115px;
  background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_right.png') repeat-x;
}

#footer .center {
  overflow: hidden; height: 115px;
  background: url('../Images/Layout/footer_middle.png') no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure this will this accommodate for the fact the center image has transparency and the background image will need to be seen through it. See Link above. I'm aware the background is black at the moment it wont be later.

Comment: DreamTek, didn't you write "no scripts, no hacks"? Are you sure my variant doesn't work? I used it many times. BTW, it works in IE7.

Comment: Yes I did say it no hacks but its the best I can conjure. Unfortunately your way is sound but does not accommodate when zooming out. Still reps to you for your answer thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do what you want cross browser with CSS **only**. However despite the fact that you said no scripts (hey don't beat me ok?!) let me show how easy you can achieve it with a few lines of javascript (using jQuery but you don't need to)

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2QLa8/)

#### HTML

```
<div id="FtrM">
    <div id="FtrL"></div>
    <div id="FtrC"></div>
    <div id="FtrR"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#FtrM {
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
}
#FtrL, #FtrR, #FtrC {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}
#FtrL, #FtrR {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: black;
}

#FtrC {
    background: none;
    width: 200px;
}
```

#### JS

```
function calc() {
    $('#FtrL, #FtrR').width(($('#FtrM').width() - $('#FtrC').width()) / 2);
}
calc();
$(window).resize(calc);
```

Comment: I appreciate your effort and time. I would have used your code but your calc expression gave me an idea. I beat my css into submission. Cross browser compliant. And IE7 can kiss my A$$.
Shame I cant rate my answer as solved.

Comment: tell us what is that idea. Is it something that can do this with CSS only?

Comment: Since you are open to webkit functions see my new answer :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div class="contain">
<div class="footer">YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.contain {width:100%;}
.footer {margin:0 auto;width:300px;height:50px;}
```

Should do what you want. Unless I've misunderstood your question...
http://jsfiddle.net/2Qw6D/1/

Comment: Looked good at first glance. The problem is the left and right part have background images

Comment: I'm not sure this will this accommodate for the fact the center image has transparency and the background image will need to be seen through it. See Link above. I'm aware the background is black at the moment it wont be later.